# Set max length for all String fields through properties for database creation. Hibernate+Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have 100+ JPA classes in a project. Hibernate creates a database schema for all of them. **String** fields it makes of length 255.

Is there any way to **configure Hibernate through application.properties** file, for example, so that it creates String fields of 4000 length?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the default field length isn't possible. The `255` value is the default specified by JPA.

Answer (score 1):

Size annotation could help:

```
@Size(max = 4000)
private String name;
```

See also [this link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/spring-boot-validation-for-rest-services).

Comment: For 100+ JPA classes with thousands of String fields?!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in other area. Instead of forcing Hibernate create max length String fields I have converted the length of all created String fields to 4000.

I have created a database **by default** using Hibernate with String fields of 255 length. Then I have **converted** all String fields to 4000 length by doing the following steps.

I use PostgreSQL, so this solution is for it. For others it might need some changes.

1. I use a script:

> select 'ALTER TABLE '||table_schema||'.'||table_name||' ALTER COLUMN
>   '||column_name||' SET DATA TYPE character varying(4000);'  from
>   information_schema.columns where table_schema='public' and
>   data_type='character varying' and character_maximum_length=255

to create a number of scripts that change the length of String fields from 255 to 4000.

**Pay attention** that I might need to change **table_schema** from **public**, that is in my case, to your one.

2. Choose all created scripts and execute them in SQL-window by "execute pgScript".

As a resuult all String fields in database with 255 length will change their length to 4000.